# How to work with reduce function in JavaScript? I'm bit confused in using it

Tags: javascript, reduce

I'm bit confused in working with reduce function i have an array

```
let aa = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

and my required output is:

```
[{id:1,children:
   [{id:2,children:
        [{id:3,children:
          [{id:4,children:
            [{id:5,children:
              [{id:6,children:[{}]}]
            }]
          }]
        }]
   }]
}]
```

I wrote a function

```js
let aa = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
let cc = aa.reduce((acc, val) => {
  let obj = {
    id: val,
    children: []
  }
  acc.push(obj);
  console.log(acc[0].children)
  acc = acc[0].children
  return acc
}, [])
console.log(cc);
```

after executing I'm getting empty array but while viewing the 7th line console iam getting some what like

[image]

Please some one help me out to understand what mistake i made.

Can we make this tree using Map() in javascript

Comment: can't you use forEach array method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to save a reference to the *initial* outer array, before calling `.reduce`. Then, after calling `.reduce` and passing in the initial value, it'll construct the recursive structure, and then you can return the initial value to return the whole structure:

```js
const aa = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
const result = [];
aa.reduce((acc, val) => {
  acc[0] = {
    id: val,
    children: [{}]
  };
  return acc[0].children;
}, result);

console.log(result);
```

Another option without saving a result to the outer array is to use `reduceRight` to construct it from the inside instead:

```js
const aa = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
const result = aa.reduceRight((children, val) => ([{
  id: val,
  children
}]), [{}]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you soo much bro how fast replay

Comment: aa.reduceRight((acc, e)=> [{id:e, children: acc}], [{}]); // start with[{}]

Answer (score 4):

you can combine JS array reverse and reduce method to get your result as follows

```js
let aa = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
let result = aa.reverse().reduce((children, id) => [{ id, children }], [{}]);

console.log(result)
```